# numpy.genfromtxt() dtype to parse datetime string with AM/PM

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I have several data files with thousands of records like this:

```
4844,05/24/18 07:30:00 AM,75.312,0.428
4845,05/24/18 07:40:00 AM,75.312,0.435
4846,05/24/18 07:50:00 AM,75.312,0.429
```

and I'm trying to pull it into NumPy using `numpy.genfromtxt()` like this:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(file_name, dtype=[('recordId','i8')
    , ('trn_date','datetime64[s]'), ('temperature','f8'), ('depth','f8')]
    , delimiter=',', skip_header=2)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out the correct dtype format tuple for the trn_date field to get these datetime strings to be parsed correctly because they use AM/PM suffixes instead of being in "military time".

Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried to RTFM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to pass in a custom converter leveraging [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) for the dates with the `converters=` argument, since NumPy datetime parsing [isn't super flexible](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html#string-parsing) beyond the ISO 8601 format.

If you look at the [table of format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for `strptime` you can see it can handle AM/PM with the `%p` directive.

```
import datetime as dt

def date_parser(d_bytes):
    s = d_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    return np.datetime64(dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S %p'))

data = np.genfromtxt(
    # ... 
    converters={1: date_parser})
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an elegant solution that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is that the way numpy.getfromtxt() parses datetimes is in the format: 'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00'
e.g. '2018-05-27T01:45:45'
[See the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

The solution is to re-write the text to this format. There are a number of ways to do this such as making a new file, or maybe using StringIO.

Here is my example of cleaning the text and writing it to a new file:

```
with open(input_text, 'r') as file_io:
    for line in file_io: 
        split_line = line.split(',')
        split_datetime = split_line[1].split(' ')
        print(split_datetime)
        split_date = split_datetime[0].split('/')
        print(split_date)
        #put the date back in
        fixed_datetime = '20' + split_date[2] \
                          + '-' + split_date[0] \
                          + '-' + split_date[1] \
                          + 'T' + split_datetime[1]

        prepared_text = prepared_text + split_line[0] + ',' \
                                      + fixed_datetime[1] + ',' \
                                      + split_line[2] + ',' \
                                      + split_line[3] 

secondary_file = 'secondary_data_file.txt'

with open(secondary_file, 'w') as sec_file_io:
    sec_file_io.write(prepared_text)
```

You can do this different ways. You dtype was right though!